# Warning: Unknown event handler property `onCellClick`. It will be ignored

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

```
Warning: Unknown event handler property onCellClick. It will be ignored.
    in table (created by Table)
    in Table (created by WithStyles(Table))
```

We were using Table from material-ui old version and the `onCellClick` handler was attached to it. I tried using Table component from material-ui v1 instead but I've been seeing this warning in the console.
I searched in the MUI v1 docs but `onCellClick` isn't mentioned in the api for Table or any of its child components.

This is my code:

```
  <Dialog
    open={schedulerOpened}
    title={TITLE}
    large
    onClose={toggleScheduler}
  >
    <Table className="table-scheduler" onCellClick={onPickSlot}>
      <TableHead>
        <TableRow>
          <TableCell>
          </TableCell>
        </TableRow>
      </TableHead>
    </Table>
  </Dialog>
);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try...?
`...<TableCell onClick={onPickSlot}>....

Comment: Yes that worked. Thanks! But still confused as to why it is not working on the table component.